# how to mock navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues with jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, client-hints

I would like to mock the resolved value of [`navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorUAData/getHighEntropyValues) in my test to be a sample object.

How can I do this?

I tried:

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock(global.navigator.userAgentData);
  });
  it('uaFullVersion is defined', async () => {
     global.navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues.mockResolvedValueOnce({uaFullVersion: '1.2.3'});
     const hev = await myFunc();
     expect(hev.uaFullVersion).toBeDefined();
  });
```

myFunc:

```js
async function myFunc() {
  const hev = await navigator.userAgentData.getHighEntropyValues(["uaFullVersion"]);
  return hev;
}
```

but I get the error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHighEntropyValues')`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using `jest.spyOn` instead of the `jest.mock` at the `beforeEach`?

like:

```js
jest.spyOn(global.navigator.userAgentData,  
    'getHighEntropyValues').mockResolvedValueOnce({})
```

?

Comment: When I try that I get `Cannot spyOn on a primitive value; undefined given`, referring to global.navigator.userAgentData being undefined

Comment: Is your Jest configured to handle JSDOM?

Can you show the project repository?